# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis queue name format requirement

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying out ActiveMQ Artemis with a queue design. I want to know if there is a specified format for correct queue name validation. Also is there a default maximum length for name of the queue and supported symbols? I tried and searched for an answer but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't perform any queue name validation either for length or special symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Artemis doesn’t define any specific format for queue name and hence doesn’t do any queue name validation. But, for example, in my set up, I have defined that the queue name should always have a prefix jms.queue. So, the queue names can be anything like jms.queue.xxxx and I can validate the new queue to be created against this format.